# DNS CNAME Alias issue

Tags: dns

I've setup 2 CNAME records on our domain to point to 2 external domains from our vendor (`docs.mydomain.org -> clientdocs.vendor.com and view.mydomain.org -> clientview.vendor.com`). We manage our domain DNS internally. The vendor was able to ping the CNAME aliases from their domain network and got successful replies which also showed the correct vendor hostnames which indicated that the aliases were working correctly. I am also able to ping the aliases from within my domain network and all looks well here too. However, when I try to ping the aliases from outside my domain, for example from home, no responses are received. When I type the alias URLs in the browser it gives me a Page Not Found error when at home. If I do this from my domain network in the office, it works correctly and goes to the vendor page as expected. What could be causing this? The ping results are below, although I have replaced the domains and IP addresses:

SUCCESSFUL - from my domain network (mydomain.org) at office, and from vendor domain (vendor.com) at vendor office:

```
C:\Users\me>ping view.mydomain.org

Pinging clientview.vendor.com [168.123.45.6] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 168.123.45.6: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.6: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.6: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.6: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=121

Ping statistics for 168.123.45.6:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 35ms, Maximum = 39ms, Average = 37ms

C:\Users\me>ping docs.mydomain.org

Pinging clientdocs.vendor.com [168.123.45.7] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 168.123.45.7: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.7: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.7: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=121
Reply from 168.123.45.7: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=121

Ping statistics for 168.123.45.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 35ms, Maximum = 38ms, Average = 36ms
```

UNSUCCESSFUL - from home

```
Barrys-MBP:~ barry$ ping docs.mydomain.org
PING docs.mydomain.org (92.242.123.45): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
^C
--- docs.bicsi.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

Barrys-MBP:~ barry$ ping view.mydomain.org
PING view.mydomain.org (92.242.123.45): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
^C
--- view.bicsi.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/network tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to clear the DNS cache from my home computers. After doing that it worked fine.